# Sort structs with many numbers inside

Tags: c++, sorting, compare

I want to sort an array of structs in which each struct has an array inside. I wanted to create my custom compare() function for sort but haven't been able to yet:

```
struct box{
    int dims[6];
} boxArray[32];
```

So, there are 32 boxes, each one has 6 dimensions.

For example,

box1 has these dimensions :

> 1 2 5 10 20 30

box2:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 9

I want box2 to come out sorted before box1 because in the first two dimensions they are equal but in the next one, box 2 is smaller.

My idea was to use sort

> (boxArray,boxArray+32,customCmpBoxes)

and inside the custom function, compare recursively until one is smaller (or not) but I can't get it working.

Comment: That's the right approach - what have you tried so far for your `customCmpBoxes` function?

Comment: You don't show your compare function.  Wouldn't you pass in to the compare function, the pointer to dims, and then just compare those with a loop of some sorts?  Recursion seems overly complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool customCmpBoxes(const box& left, const box& right) {
  return std::lexicographical_compare(
    left.dims, left.dims + sizeof(left.dims)/sizeof(left.dims[0]),
    right.dims, right.dims + sizeof(right.dims)/sizeof(right.dims[0]));
}
```